# FutureBuilder is not working when i use timer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

These are my two different methods. The method getCommunitiesList is working, it will show `circleProgressBar` and then the result. The function `getCommunitiesList_old` is not working it is still showing only `circleProgressBar` and I know problem is not in `FutureBuilder`. The problem is inside this function. Can anybody please help me to identify the issue?

```
Future<List<CommunitieModel>> getCommunitiesList()async{
  List<CommunitieModel> data=List();
  for(int i=1;i<30;i++) {
    data.add(CommunitieModel());//title:"Hi Temple $i",details: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...",imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQufRouQz5g0chR_vkUnDPbYpYdorS5FtT6N9asmkp-MqhDscJ-&s"));
  }
  return data;
}

Future<List<CommunitieModel>> getCommunitiesList_old()async{
  await Timer(Duration(seconds: 5),(){
    List<CommunitieModel> data=List();
    for(int i=1;i<30;i++) {
      data.add(CommunitieModel());//title:"Hi Temple $i",details: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...",imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQufRouQz5g0chR_vkUnDPbYpYdorS5FtT6N9asmkp-MqhDscJ-&s"));
    }
    return data;
  });//.tick;
}
```

This code works and provided by 
Crazy Lazy Cat

```
Future<List<CommunitieModel>> getCommunitiesList_old() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  List<CommunitieModel> data = List();
  for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
    data.add(
        CommunitieModel()); //title:"Hi Temple $i",details: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...",imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQufRouQz5g0chR_vkUnDPbYpYdorS5FtT6N9asmkp-MqhDscJ-&s"));
  }
  return data;
}
```

I have one more doubt 
Why this code is not working

```
Future<List<SimpleCardModel>> getTempleList()async{
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1),(){
    List<SimpleCardModel> data = List();
    for (int i = 11; i < 44; i++) {
      data.add(SimpleCardModel(title: "Hi Temple $i",
          details: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...",
          imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQufRouQz5g0chR_vkUnDPbYpYdorS5FtT6N9asmkp-MqhDscJ-&s"));
    }
    return data;
  });


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Future.delayed`

```
Future<List<CommunitieModel>> getCommunitiesList_old() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  List<CommunitieModel> data = List();
  for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
    data.add(
        CommunitieModel()); //title:"Hi Temple $i",details: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when ...",imageUrl: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQufRouQz5g0chR_vkUnDPbYpYdorS5FtT6N9asmkp-MqhDscJ-&s"));
  }
  return data;
}
```

Comment: The `Timer` will only executes the given callback after the specified duration.

Comment: Here the callback returns the data to `Timer`. But the `Timer` doesn't care about the result and will just ignore it.

Comment: please check my question i updated with one more doubt

Comment: The problem is the `return data` returns the value to `Future.delayed` not to `getTempleList`. you have to specify another return before `Future.delayed` to get that data. I am not native English. pls pardon me.